# Magento Onepage Checkout

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I have magento site. there are order summary page. i want to remove that order summary page. I do not want to use any extension. Please suggest solution

Comment: Funny... 200 means "Success" :-?

Comment: Check your php.ini file and make sure upload_max_filesize and post_max_size are set to a size that allows for what you're uploading.

Comment: i am uploading using file chunk(5 MB) so that function not required to set.

Answer (score 0):

Could be caused by a corrupt .htaccess file. Check to see if there is an .htaccess file in the directory where the error is being generated or any directory above in the tree. If so, temporarily rename the .htaccess file and refresh the page. If the error does not reappear, the .htaccess file is the issue. Repair the file or leave it disabled. Repairing it is as easy as re-generating the file, so I'd suggest trying that first.

Also, you can check your server error logs for more detailed information on the error.

Comment: i have not .htaccess file. i can create it what content i have to add there to remove this error.

Comment: @amit The file could be hidden. Have you checked for hidden files?

Comment: I have my server log also how can i identify my error from that

Comment: how can i check hidden files.

Comment: @amit On Windows: (1) Open Folder Options by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Folder Options. (2) Click the View tab. (3) Under Advanced settings, click Show hidden files, folders, and drives, and then click OK.

Comment: @amit Are you using a hosting service? Maybe you can ask them for assistance?

Comment: I have asked them they told my file size is 96 MB so i want to modify that size externally

Comment: and i am using file chunk technology so it divide file in to small part then upload it

Comment: @amit I'm not sure where to go from here. I think the support team on your hosting are much more likely to find the solution to your problem. Good luck